# Printing Directly to my Deskjet 2752e Printer network using TCP Connection

Tags: java, android, tcp, printing, pcl

I'm encountering difficulties when attempting to print simple text using PCL in Java with my Deskjet 2752e printer. The printer [supports HP PCL 3 GUI, HP PCLm (HP Apps/UPD)](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-deskjet-2700e-all-in-one-series/2100187844/model/2100187848/document/c07062180#:%7E:text=to%201000%20pages-,Print%20languages,-HP%20PCL%203), and URF (AirPrint)[1](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-deskjet-2700e-all-in-one-series/2100187844/model/2100187848/document/c07062180#:%7E:text=to%201000%20pages-,Print%20languages,-HP%20PCL%203). Despite multiple attempts and variations of the PCL code, I have been unable to achieve successful printing. Even sending plain text results in no response from the printer.

My objective is to send a straightforward text print job directly to my printer network, with the ability to position the text using x and y coordinates. To accomplish this, I am developing an Android app that can print text without prompting the user for print settings or leaving the app. It is crucial for the app to automatically and efficiently send the necessary data to the printer and initiate the printing process promptly. As the sole user of the app, I aim to streamline the printing experience and eliminate unnecessary prompts, thereby making the app faster and more efficient.

Here is the last code I have been working with:

```
private void sendPrintJob() {
    System.out.println("Connecting to the printer...");
    try (Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.6", 9100)) {
        System.out.println("Connected.");

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.write(generatePCL3GUI().getBytes());
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        System.out.println("Print job successfully sent.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public String generatePCL3GUI() {
    StringBuilder pclCode = new StringBuilder();
    
    pclCode.append("\u001B%-12345X@PJL JOB\r\n");
    pclCode.append("@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE=PCL3GUI\r\n");
    
    pclCode.append("\u001B*s0M"); // Set color mode to monochrome
    pclCode.append("\u001B*t300R"); // Set resolution to 300 dpi
    pclCode.append("\u001B*r0F"); // Set orientation to portrait

    
    pclCode.append("\u001B(8U"); // Select font: Courier New
    pclCode.append("\u001BE"); // Start of the print job
    pclCode.append("\u001B&a100H"); // Set position (x=100, y=100)
    pclCode.append("Hello, world!\r\n"); // Print text
    
    pclCode.append("\u001B%-12345X@PJL EOJ\r\n");

    return pclCode.toString();
}
```

Comment: From: https://developers.hp.com/hp-printer-command-languages-pcl/doc/hp-pcl3 `PCL 3GUI is used in most DeskJet series printers and HP DesignJet large-formate printers (plotters). It uses a proprietary compressed Raster Transfer Language format that is not compatible with standard PCL 3.`

Answer (score 0):

As for the document input format you could also consider PDF.
Rendering PDF to PCLm is [supported by jrender](https://github.com/HPInc/jipp/blob/master/sample/jrender/src/main/java/sample/jrender/Main.java).

If you query the `document-format-supported` from the printer via IPP, you might also see `text/plain`. Submitting a printable document via IPP is [supported by the ipp-client](https://github.com/gmuth/ipp-client-kotlin) and offers more features than jet-direct via port 9100.